# Why the Div tag is not working in Mozilla and IE?

Tags: css

The code given below is not working in mozilla and Internet Explorer but correctly working with google chrome. I have used the code in the index template of the home page of a wordpress site.

code:

```
<h1>
    <div  style=" background: #808080;" align="center" >
    Welcome to Braddocks blog. Free dating advice from a world famous Dating Coach!
    </div>
</h1>
```

Please let me know what is the problem?

Comment: what is not working?? background color or alignment?

Comment: the background and alignment are not working

Answer (score 2):

`<div>` is not valid inside `<h1>`. Instead just apply the necessary attributes to the header:

```
<h1 style="background: #808080; text-align: center;">Welcome to...</h1>
```

Comment: use `background-color: #808080;`

Comment: `background` works just fine and it overrides any other background attributes if they are set

Answer (score 0):

div and h1 all block level elements,Unnecessary add h1 outer to the div,so try this:

```
<div  style="display:block; background: #808080;text-align:center;">
    Welcome to Braddocks blog. Free dating advice from a world famous Dating Coach!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in Firefox. The previous answer is correct though. The h1 must be inside the div (and for seo there should only be one h1 per page). Do a `text-align:center` on the div and `margin: 0 auto` on the div to center the div. If you want to text inside the h1 to be left align put a `text-align: left` on the h1. I would discourage inline styling.

```
<div style="background: #808080; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;" >
    <h1>Welcome to Braddocks blog. Free dating advice from a world famous Dating Coach!</h1>
</div>
```